# How to find the which line of code triggers $digest already in progress in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular.js application which reports error in the browser console:

`Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`

Can you please tell me how to find which code triggers this error?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my stack trace:

`Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
    at http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular.js/angular.js:78:12
    at beginPhase (http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular.js/angular.js:10995:15)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular.js/angular.js:10795:11)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular.js/angular.js:16514:17)
    at http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular.js/angular.js:2331:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular.js/angular.js:213:11)
    at HTMLInputElement.eventHandler (http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular.js/angular.js:2330:5)
    at scroll (http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular.js/angular.js:3479:26)
    at http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular.js/angular-route.js:852:15 angular.js:8296`

Comment: Are you running a `$scope.apply` somewhere that is tripping this up?

Comment: No. I'm not using $scope.apply anywhere in the application. I read the documentation about this error and I still cannot find what parts of my app trigger this. But I use `angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker` and `ng-table` as dependencies so they may call $scope.apply internally...

Comment: I see others (2 users so far) have voted to close my question.. Why? What is wrong with it?

Comment: It may help if you produce a jsFiddle that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Its a very broad question as it stands. This can be triggered by a number of things. Try removing pieces of the code until it goes away, and see what you removed. That's all I got.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. binary search i.e. cut the app in half and check when the error stops. then focus on that.

Or go into the angular source and put a breakpoint in the line that is reported. Then backtrace using the call stack.

Both options might end up time consuming, but i would start with the call stack. Good luck.